# Navigation Service in WPF

Tags: wpf, navigationservice

I created a simple application in WPF and added one page. I also added one button to the main window, and when I click on it, it brings the page added. But now, I want to go back from the page to the main windows by using another button.

I tried to use:

```
MainMenu n = new MainMenu();
this.NavigationService.Navigate(n);
```

but I got this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it by adding a frame inside MainWindow.xaml and redirecting it to the page i want.

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    frame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml",UriKind.Relative));    
 }
```

frame is the name of my new `frame`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for:

```
void backButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
    {
        this.NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
}
```

[navigationservice.goback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.goback(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi @Kory Gill..I tried what you said but still got                                     Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception