# How can i navigated between page wtih wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodellocator

i'm new in WPF and i would like navigate between different page like in UWP (thanks to ViewModelLocator).
I'm programming with mvvm pattern

With UWP it's so easy 
=>

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(()=>SimpleIoc.Default);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<HomeDeconnectedViewModel>();


            NavigationService navigationPage = new NavigationService();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => navigationPage);

            navigationPage.Configure("HomeDeconnected", typeof(HomeDeconnected));
```

Thanks everybody

**Edit**
To solve this issues i use this link 
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Simple-navigation-2be2ef4a
i've just use mvvmLight in additionnal and the difference is small

(We can close this issue)

Comment: IIRC, NavigationService is available in WPF too. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168840/navigation-service-in-wpf) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks but he doesn't use mvvm pattern =/

Comment: The usual approach is viewmodel first. And usercontrols rather than Pages.